# Pandas merge: df1.merge(df2, on='Date') does not merge and the left dataframe df1 stays the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: no new column names appeared?]

As you can see, Pdf_VaR2 and Pdf are the same and Pdf_VaR2 did not change

I have checked the data type of the date, they are definitely in the same datetime format.

Now I can get around this by manually assigning columns since I had manipulated it earlier such that the Date column is exactly the same, but wondering why it went wrong.

Comment: `df.merge` is not inplace.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with Pdf_VaR2=Pdf_VaR2.merge(...) instead. thanks for helping me troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

see [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) .

pd.merge return a Dataframe.

You should use .head method after df.merge.

look like :

```
df.merge().head()
```

or assignment to a new object.

```
new_df = df.merge(..., on="")
print(new_df.head())
```

or use inplace args:

```
df.merge(..., on="", inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```